# async dynamoDB methods run twice

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, async-await

I'm having trouble coding my lambda functions for an API Gateway in AWS. I don't know why some dynamoDB methods run twice. It seems to be some wrong use of async/await technique. It even happened with SQS or SNS methods.

Here is on of my functions:

```
const orderPut = async (orderID: string, status:BasicOrderStatus): Promise<APIGatewayProxyResult> => {

let response: APIGatewayProxyResult; // Init variables

try {
    ...

    console.log("blabla"); // THIS LOG APPEARS JUST ONCE IN CONSOLE
    
    let params = {...;

    await docClient.update(params, function (err, data) {
        if (err) {
            console.error("Unable to update order status. Error: ", JSON.stringify(err, null, 2));
        } else {
            console.log("Update Order Status succeeded: ", JSON.stringify(data, null, 2)); // THIS LOGS APPEARS TWICE IN CONSOLE
        }
    }).promise();

    response = createSuccessResponse() // Creates successful response

} catch (e) {
    response = createErrorResponse(e) // creates error response
}

return Promise.resolve(response) }
```

I checked and I'm sure it is not my lambda function executing twice. For example I can see my logs appearing just once on the console, but the logs from the dynamoDB method appearing twice.

Its happening in all of muy functions, but not in every dynamoDB method, or not every time. Super weird, can't understand why.

I'm using Nodejs

Any help? Thanks a lot in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, because you are supplying the callback and trying to use the promisified version as well.

Either use promises or callbacks. i.e

With promises

```
try {
    const data = await docClient.update(params).promise();
    console.log("Update Order Status succeeded: ", JSON.stringify(data, null, 2)); // THIS LOGS APPEARS TWICE IN CONSOLE
} catch (err) {
    console.error("Unable to update order status. Error: ", JSON.stringify(err, null, 2));
}
```

or callbacks.

```
docClient.update(params, function (err, data) {
    if (err) {
        console.error("Unable to update order status. Error: ", JSON.stringify(err, null, 2));
    } else {
        console.log("Update Order Status succeeded: ", JSON.stringify(data, null, 2)); // THIS LOGS APPEARS TWICE IN CONSOLE
    }
});
```

Comment: Thank you @kg99 :) Now I understand! I removed the callbacks and not its running only once!